# Editing HTML page using python 3.5.2 and Dominate

Tags: python, html, python-3.5, dominate

I have an HTML page which I want to edit using a python script. I am using the [Dominate](https://github.com/Knio/dominate) library

Here's a barebones example.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>asdjasda</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>THIS IS A TEST</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Simple HTML right?
Here's the python script:

```
import dominate
from dominate.tags import *

page = open('index.html','r',encoding='utf-8')

with page.head:
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='tts.css')
page.close()
```

I get the following error when I run this script.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "script.py", line 6, in <module>  
    with page.head:  
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'head'
```

My HTML does have a 'head'.

How do I use dominate to edit my file?

Comment: Dominate is NOT an HTML parser. It is strictly for creating new documents, not parsing existing html files. You need something like https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: @Knio Yup... I gave up on Dominate after a couple of attempts and started using BeautifulSoup instead. 
Learned it the hard way

Comment: Somewhat confusingly, there is the Python package https://github.com/Knio/dominate (which is a great package IMHO), and Nodejs package https://github.com/ryanmorr/dominate, which is a parser.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is that what `open()` function returns does not have the attribute `head`.

You should use `document` from the Dominate library.

Try this:

```
page = open('index.html','r',encoding='utf-8')
page_str = page.read()

doc = dominate.document(page_str)

with doc.head:
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='tts.css')

print(doc)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It does work but for some reason messes up the entire document. Also, it doesn't make any changed to the original HTML file

Comment: It put the h1 tag i had in the body inside the `title` tag

Comment: Dominate is NOT an HTML parser. This code dumps raw html into the title parameter of a new dominate document.