# Add HTML paragraph to the beginning of Dominate Document

Tags: html, dominate

From the Dominate github:

The document class also provides helpers to allow you to directly add nodes to the body tag.

```
d = document()
d += h1('Hello, World!')
d += p('This is a paragraph.')
print(d)


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Dominate</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I add a paragraph before the existing paragraph?

I tried:

```
d = p("Offer Ends Soon") + d
```

Got this error
Error: TypeError
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'p' and 'document'

I tried:

```
d += p("Offer Ends Soon")
```

But this puts the new paragraph at the bottom, not the top

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Dominate</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
        <p>Offer Ends Soon</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you can prepend tags into `document()` with Dominate. `document()` is pretty non-malleable in terms of modification, intended for quick prototyping only. You may need to just file a feature request at the GitHub repo for the library.

Comment: From the comments on: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45659712/5281962 . "Dominate is NOT an HTML parser. It is strictly for creating new documents, not parsing existing html files."

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You can't prepend tags using `document()`.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45659712/5281962):

> Dominate is NOT an HTML parser. It is strictly for creating new documents, not parsing existing html files